# Approaches to inference from an audit sample

Tags: sampling, inference

Here's my situation:

- I have data on two attributes of entities for a population.
- I have more accurate data for these two attributes for a sample of the population.
- The sample size is equal to the square root of the population size.
- The sample can not be considered to be truly random.

What are statistically valid approaches I can take to produce a range of estimated sums for these two attributes for the population?

Comment: Exactly what was the sample design?  Was the probability of selection into the sample related in any way to the values of the attributes-or to something associated with the attributes?  It would help to see the table of  the two sources of information ("data" , "sample") for one of the attributes.